# BootstrapTable AngularJS extension with data loaded async not working

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-table

I am using BootstrapTable AangularJS extension from [here](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/blob/master/src/extensions/angular/bootstrap-table-angular.js)

And [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/T2AHwn?p=preview) shows example on using with extension. But the example uses static data generated before table is rendered. But I am trying to make it work with data that is loaded dynamically (assume ajax request).  But this is not working. The data is not rendered.

[Plnkr example with data loaded async](http://plnkr.co/edit/t0vKnI6tnd0Elfs4bnBj?p=preview)

```
angular.module('app', ['bsTable'])
    .controller('MainController', function ($scope, $timeout) {

function makeRandomRows () {
    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        rows.push(
          {
            index: i,
            id: 'row ' + i,
            name: 'GOOG' + i,
            flagImage: '4'
        }
        );
    }
    return rows;
}

$timeout(function(){
    console.log("timedout");
      $scope.bsTableControl.data  = makeRandomRows({ workspace: "test"});
}, 2000);

    var rows = makeRandomRows();

    $scope.bsTableControl = {
        options: {
            data: [],
            rowStyle: function (row, index) {
                return { classes: 'none' };
            },
            cache: false,
            height: 400,
            striped: true,
            pagination: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            pageList: [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200],
            search: true,
            showColumns: true,
            showRefresh: false,
            minimumCountColumns: 2,
            clickToSelect: false,
            showToggle: true,
            maintainSelected: true,
            columns: [{
                field: 'state',
                checkbox: true
            }, {
                field: 'index',
                title: '#',
                align: 'right',
                valign: 'bottom',
                sortable: true
            }, {
                field: 'id',
                title: 'Item ID',
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'bottom',
                sortable: true
            }, {
                field: 'name',
                title: 'Item Name',
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle',
                sortable: true
            }, {
                field: 'flag',
                title: 'Flag',
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle'
            }]
        }
    };

 });

<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <h1>Angular bsTable</h1>
  <div>
    <table bs-table-control="bsTableControl"></table>
  </div>

</body>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. I just need to do bsTable initialization code once data is loaded instead of initializing before.

[Updated plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/B3Pac3LUJoTD1aPzABmA?p=preview)

```
$timeout(function(){
        console.log("timedout");


            $scope.bsTableControl = {
            options: {
                data: makeRandomRows({ workspace: "test"}),
                rowStyle: function (row, index) {
                    return { classes: 'none' };
                },
                cache: false,
                height: 400,
                striped: true,
                pagination: true,
                pageSize: 10,
                pageList: [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200],
                search: true,
                showColumns: true,
                showRefresh: false,
                minimumCountColumns: 2,
                clickToSelect: false,
                showToggle: true,
                maintainSelected: true,
                columns: [{
                    field: 'state',
                    checkbox: true
                }, {
                    field: 'index',
                    title: '#',
                    align: 'right',
                    valign: 'bottom',
                    sortable: true
                }, {
                    field: 'id',
                    title: 'Item ID',
                    align: 'center',
                    valign: 'bottom',
                    sortable: true
                }, {
                    field: 'name',
                    title: 'Item Name',
                    align: 'center',
                    valign: 'middle',
                    sortable: true
                }, {
                    field: 'flag',
                    title: 'Flag',
                    align: 'center',
                    valign: 'middle'
                }]
            }
        };


    }, 2000);
```